# How to "wake up" msdtc on local instance of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, msdtc

I am trying to use MSDTC to create a transaction that spans the local instance of SQL Server Express and a SQL Server 2012 database.

The first time I run my unit tests after rebooting I get "msdtc is unavailable" when I try to open a connection to the local server within a transaction, I can run the tests several times and get the same result. If I go into Component Services the Computers folder will be empty for around 5 seconds and then `My Computer` will eventually appear. I can then successfully run the Unit Tests, without doing anything further in the Component Services window. So it seems like the Component Services window is starting something up in the background, but what?

```
For Each row As DataRow In ObjectIdsTable.Rows
    Using scope As New Transactions.TransactionScope
        Using serverCon = New SqlConnection(_serverConn)
            Using syncConn As New SqlConnection(_clientConn)
                serverCon.Open()
                syncConn.Open()  **ERROR HAPPENS HERE**

                ... Do work Here ...

            End Using
        End Using
        scope.Complete()
    End Using
Next
```

I suppose I could rewrite the code to avoid using MSDTC but isn't this exactly what it is for?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. there is a service called Distributed Transaction Coordinator that was set to start manually. Setting that to Automatic fixed the problem.

It is not the first time that being forced to present the problem in a complete/logical manner so as to create a proper `SO` question has helped me resolve it myself.